# Unable to parse multiple values to ssrs rdlc report's one TextBox

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I used Session array and values parsed to another page from Checklistbox. but unable to that multiple values display on a ssrs rdlc report's TextBox.

//Checklistbox Selected values display

if (Session["Values"] != null)
               {  ArrayList arr = (ArrayList)Session["Values"];

```
                  foreach ( string  item in arr)
                   {

                    Response.Write(item + "<BR/>");

                    ReportParameter p1 = new ReportParameter("ItemsParam", item+ "");
                    ReportViewer2.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p1 });
                    ReportViewer2.Visible = true;
                    ReportViewer2.DataBind(); // Added
                    ReportViewer2.LocalReport.Refresh();



                 }
```

Comment: Are you intending to refresh the report every time you add a new param?

Comment: yes. I intended like that. but  above code's  "item+"  last value only display on SSRS ,RDLC report's TextBox